# Orbeon 4.2 forwarding session cookie to custom persistence layer

Tags: orbeon

Orbeon is integrated into another webapp. `oxf.http.state` is set to `none`.

When loading a form in form runner, external session cookies are not forwarded to the persistence. Despite that `oxf.http.forward-headers` and `oxf.http.forward-cookies` are set to according values.

When loading a simple form which isn't rendered by form runner the cookies are nicely forwarded with the requests in preprocessing step to the same server.

And after loading a simple form and forwarding session cookie atleast once, all the request from form runner also contain that cookie till the session expires.

So the question is - is it possible to forward external session cookies to the same server from form runner to custom persistence layer?

Or the only way is to make a dummy request each time to add the cookie to the http client?

Comment: And another thing what I noticed about the cookies in orbeon. When `oxf.http.state value="session"`, then on the first request to the simple form, request from preprocessor, which must have forwarded cookie in its header contains cookie with forwarded cookie name and value of ORBEONSESSIONID cookie value. That seems like a bug.

Comment: This sounds similar to [this bug](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1070), which we closed recently because we could no longer reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, this looks similar to [issue #1070](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1070), that was marked fixed for 4.3, as the problem wasn't happening with that version. So I recommend you upgrade to 4.3.

If the problem persists with the latest version, I'd recommend you update your question with specific steps we can follow to reproduce this.